# How to connect Visual Studio 2015 to an existing Gitlab project?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gitlab

There is an on-premise instance of [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) installed. There are Visual Studio projects in this instance. What is the easiest way of connecting Visual Studio 2015 to one of the projects?

With GitHub, you can do it by selecting "Connect to GitHub" as on the following picture:
[image]

and then pasting the repository url. There is no GitLab option in the drop down. What is the easiest way of configuring Visual Studio 2015 to work with a solution from gitlab repository? By work I mean to have your usual source control bindings to the repository.

Note, that this question is probably useful in more general context of connecting to *any* git repository that is not GitHub, and does not have direct support with built-in Visual Studio menu, not just to GitLab repository.

Comment: The following is a decent example: https://www.huber.xyz/?p=284

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, get the clone using command line:

```
git clone <repository url>
```

Then in Visual Studio, in the Team Explorer pane, select the connect button and look for Local Git Repositories "tab":

[image]

Press Add, as indicated on the picture, and select the folder you cloned your repository too.

When the process finishes, you can double-click the added repo to "connect" to it, and then select and open a solution it contains. After that follow your usual Visual Studio git workflow.

Comment: You can even clone the repository in Visual Studio itself. No CLI required.

Comment: but if you commit changes, they are not being committed to the git lab repo, just the local branch? Or am i misinterpreting this.

Comment: @JacobAlley in git you always commit from your working copy to staging area. You need to push to propagate it to the server.

Comment: sorry, i meant to say push...can you push from VS or do you need to go into the command prompt to do so

Comment: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied

Comment: I did it without using CLI, just by the clone option in  TeamExplorer

Answer (score 7):

Now its simple to Use GitLab with Visual studio 2015 just add GitLab Extensions to Visual studio and you are there.

1. Steps for Adding GitLab Extensions to Visual studio

[image]

2. In Search of Extensions and updates choose online and search GitLab.

[image]

Comment: it is full of login bugs

Answer (score 2):

For using gitlab when you have ssh keys and also your ssh key have passphrase, you have to follow instructions as follow (don’t forget to upload your public key to gitlab)(also you must use a private key which its format is openssh):

1. Have your project folder and its files.
2. Have Git Bash installed on your system.
3. Using git bash, go to your project directory.
4. `git config --global user.name "your-name"`
5. `git config --global user.email "your-email-address"`
6. `git init`
7. `ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add “private-key-local-address”; git remote
   add origin “online-repo-address”’` (will be asked for passphrase)
8. `git add .`
9. `git commit -m “initial commit”`
10. `ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add “private-key-local-address”; git push
     -u origin master'` (will be asked for passphrase)
11. in visual studio, right-click on the solution, select add solution to source control. (visual studio will automatically find repository)

For further commits, you can commit changes in visual studio (ONLY COMMIT) and then repeat step 10 to push them to gitlab servers.

edit: for send a project from visual studio to gitlab use `git remote add origin` and for get project from gitlab to visual studio use `git clone` instead!